# Blender game - explosion type motion

Tags: game-engine

I have a setup like this: [image]

My task is to create three types of motions: rotate each piece individually, rotate the whole thing, and an explosion type of motion.

I've been unable to figure out how to do the last one, ie. all the pieces would move away from the center one (the one in the very middle, not the selected one). How can I do this?

In case what I'm asking is unclear, I've impemented this in opengl before [here](http://robus.info/private/opengl.exe) - press '1' on the keyboard once, and it will do what I'm trying to achieve in blender.

Comment: Just to let you know, most people here will not click on your link to a `.exe`.

Comment: @David I do realize (hell, even the file size is pretty sketchy), I tried making a video with some screen recorder - turned out all back though :(

Answer (score 2):

You can use the *manipulate center points* option for this. It works best with a pivot set to the 3D cursor so select the center cube, and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>>*Cursor to selected* to send the cursor there. Then hit <kbd>.</kbd> to set the pivot to the 3D cursor.

[image]

Enable the *manipulate center points* option by clicking the arrow with the dots over it. Now simply scale the all the objects to send them further away. (<kbd>S</kbd>

Comment: Great! One more question: how can I incorporate this into the game engine?

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24612/how-do-i-play-animations-in-the-game-engine/24614#24614

Comment: This link to solve ^^ :)