# How do I play animations in the game engine?

Tags: animation, game-engine

Okay, so this may be a duplicate, but I sure couldn't find it. In  [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24253/blender-game-explosion-type-motion/24268?noredirect=1#comment35880_24268) question the OP wanted to know how to make his animation play.

**Scenario:** I have an animation on my object (or armature) and I want to be able to play them in the game engine. How do I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be done in the game logic view using an *action* actuator. First ensure the *Armature Modifier* on your mesh is at the top of the *Modifier stack* or at least above *Subserf*.
Change the screen layout to *Game logic* and the physics type to *Blender Game* using the drop-downs at the top of the screen.

[image]

Select your object that you want the animation to play from and in the *logic Editor* space, (large grey empty bottom of the screen) click the *Add Sensor* button and select *always*.

[image]

Now remember that a sensor sets conditions for something to happen, so you may not want to use the *Always* in different circumstances.

Click *Add Controller* > *AND* along with *Add Actuator* > *Action*.

Select your animation in the light grey box on the action actuator

[image]

and set the start and end values to encompass the entire length of the animation. My animation is 60 frames long, so I set start to 1 and end to 60.

[image]

The last step is to connect all the little dots in between the boxes so that it forms one string of logic. **Always > AND > Action**

[image]

Press <kbd>P</kbd> to play the game and see the animation play.

Comment: That is if you want the animation to play in one single .blend file. Apparently, [playing animations in separate files loaded via libload is not possible](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27274/how-to-use-playaction-on-libloaded-objects).

Comment: Nice tutorial, very useful. I have a question: if i use modifier to animate a mesh, how can i get keyframes from it to feed in the action actuator?
I use Blender 2.75 wave modifier to make a simple water surface on a subdivided plane. It loooks nice but i can't "play" it in the game engine since i don't have any keyframes. Do you know a way to get this working? I tried to place some keyframes on the wave modifier but it didn't do anything. Merci

Comment: while, animating with modifiers and shapekeys and such is a long way from being fully supported, I would recommend using drivers on an animated armature to power them. i don't know enough about drivers to really say much more than that but google looks like it has some stuff.